# remove attribute on document node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to remove the xsi:schemaLocation but I don't get it to work, 
I think I do something wrong in wt:Envelope/wt:Body/wt:MessageParts/*[not(name() ='xsi:schemaLocation')] definition, but don't know how to solve this

xml source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{AAE4C191-6D18-4823-A29D-9C6CA68113C2}</MessageId>
    <Action>http://tempuri.org/VendPaymentsService/find</Action>
  </Header>
  <Body>
   <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
     <Document xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 pain.001.001.03.xsd" 
          xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
          ....
        </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      </Document>
    </MessageParts>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

My xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:wt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
                xmlns:s1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/VendPayments" 
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-1" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="wt:Envelope/wt:Body/wt:MessageParts/*[not(name() ='xsi:schemaLocation')]" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document 
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 pain.001.001.03.xsd" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
..
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What result are you trying to get? Do you want the `<Document>` element and its children without the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:copy-of>` performs a deep copy; you cannot exclude individual nodes. Note also that `xsi:schemaLocation` is an **attribute**, not an **element**.

Try it this way, perhaps?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wt:Envelope/wt:Body/wt:MessageParts/*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:
You should **never** be required to use a hack like this:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;</xsl:text>
```

If you want your output to have utf-8 encoding, say so in the `<output>` element.